# Wait for FB request before UITableView loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview

I am trying to use Facebook's iOS SDK and load a list of friends in a UITableView. When I put the following code in `viewDidLoad` it seemingly doesn't get added to the UITableView. (Where **users** is the NSMutableArray)

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
        [users addObject:friend.name];
    }
}];
```

I've tried adding:

```
[friendsTableView beginUpdates];
[friendsTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:users withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[friendsTableView endUpdates];
```

To update the UITableView after the request finishes with no change.

What can I do either load the UITableView after the request or update the UITableView when the request finishes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot just pass any array to `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`. It expects an array filled with index paths — hence the name.

what you want is to reload the tableview once the response is received.

```
FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
[friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              NSDictionary* result,
                                              NSError *error) {
    NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
    for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
        NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
        [users addObject:friend.name];
    }
    [friendsTableView reloadData]; //<------
}];
```

while tableviews datasource & delegate methods use `users` as source.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have added `[friendsTableView reloadData];` in the block but the UITableView only populates when you go to a different view (e.g. in a Tab Bar Controller) and back. It doesn't load right off the bat. Why is this?